# 2 Simple 2-variable functions limits

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I think I have found the limits below, although I am new to multi-variable functions and I am unsure of whether the method I obeyed is correct. I would kindly ask if someone could say whether there is something wrong and even if there was not, maybe suggest another way of solving those.
1)
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})}{x^4+y^4}$$
I used polar coordinates; $(x,y)=r(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$:
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{r^2})}{r^4(\cos^4\phi+\sin^4\phi)}$$
We know $\alpha = \cos^4\phi+\sin^4\phi> 0$
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{r^2})}{r^4}$$
Let $t = \frac{1}{r^2}$, then
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{t^2}{e^{t}}$$
Using L'Hopital's rule:
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2t}{e^{t}}\stackrel{\text{L'H}}{\longrightarrow}\frac{1}{\alpha}\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2}{e^{t}}=0.$$
I know exponent can be replaced with an lower approximation such as a monomial of a high power.

2)
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}y\ln(x^2+y^2)$$
Again I use $(x,y)=r(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$:
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}r\sin\phi\ln(r^2)$$
$$|r\sin\phi\ln(r^2)|\leq|r\ln(r^2)|=\left|\frac{\ln(r^2)}{\frac{1}{r}}\right|\stackrel{\text{L'H}}{\longrightarrow}\left|\frac{\frac{1}{r^2}(2r)}{-\frac{1}{r^2}}\right|\stackrel{r\rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow}0$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}y\ln(x^2+y^2)=0.$$
Something about those solutions makes me insecure. Thanks for help and sorry if such limits were already posted. I was genuinely searching for them.